Change in mass in chemical change
In a chemical change, whenever energy is absorbed or released, there must be a change in mass . Howsoever small it may be.
So in that case, is a sub-atomic particle(s) responsible for the change in mass, or is it just the energy changes in the chemical reaction ,due to changed configuration, which manifest itself as energy change. Indirectly, I want to ask is there a sub atomic particle which behaves a carrier of chemical energy?

Mass is not a conserved property. Only total energy is conserved. So it is not the case that when a reaction occurs with a decrease in total mass $\Delta m$ this means a particle with mass $\Delta m$ has to be emitted.
If you take a simple reaction like:
$$ \mathrm{H} + \mathrm{H} \to \mathrm{H}_2 $$
This releases an energy of about $4.5~\mathrm{eV}$ so the mass of the $\mathrm{H}_2$ molecule is smaller than the masses of the two $\mathrm{H}$ atoms by $4.5~\mathrm{eV}/c^2$ or about $8 \times 10^{-36}~\mathrm{kg}$. But this doesn't mean some particle with this mass is emitted. Instead some of the initial mass is converted to energy in accordance with Einstein's famous equation $E=mc^2$ and hence the mass decreases.
In a typical reaction this energy is converted to the kinetic energy of the reaction products, though it could be emitted as a photon (which is of course massless).
